How to import local variable to layouts in express js project?
I have a view page that uses the layout via <%- include('layouts/search_job'); %>. I want to import a variable into this layout without affecting the parent view. Here's how I'm attempting it:
exports.lysearch = async (req, res) => {
try {
const listCities = function_new.listCities || [];
 return res.render('layouts/search_job', { listCities });
} catch (error) {
  console.error('error:', error);
   return res.status(500).send('error 500');
  } 
};

In my layout (search_job.ejs), this is my code:
<select id="s_loc">
<% if (listCities && listCities.length > 0) { %>
 <% listCities.forEach(function(item) { %>
  <option value="<%= item.cit_id %>"><%= item.cit_name %></option>
  <% }); %>
<% } %>
</select>

However, when I run the project, it renders an error: listCities is not defined at eval. How can I resolve this?
I've tried everything I can, but I only succeed when I import the variable into the parent view

are you missing the - in %>. I think it should be <%- include('layouts/search_job'); -%>

I have tried adding a "-" after, but that is not the problem. Because in reality, I can still display layouts from before.

How did you get this function_new.listCities?There is no code about what this is ? The issue lies in here.Show the code of function_new.listCities.

This is small of my code in function_new.js.
const listCities = [
{
"_id": "66666d51e2b01fd29e8e18e1",
"cit_id": 1,
"cit_name": "City 1"
},
{
"_id": "66666d51e2b01fd29e8e18e3",
"cit_id": 2,
"cit_name": "City 2"
}]
module.exports = { listCities};

@TúNgôNgọc , I have posted my detailed answer.Please check and let me know your feedback.

@TúNgôNgọc, function_new.listCities || []; this line causes error. This is not the right way to import listCities.The correct way I mentioned in my answer.

Do the following steps in order to resolve the issue.
function_new.js
const listCities = [ 
{ "_id": "66666d51e2b01fd29e8e18e1", "cit_id": 1, "cit_name": "City 1" }, 
{ "_id": "66666d51e2b01fd29e8e18e3", "cit_id": 2, "cit_name": "City 2" }
];

module.exports =  listCities ;

Then import the module into exports.lysearch and then send data into the ejs template like this.
//align this import based on which directoty `function_new.js` exist.I assume it is in the main directory
const listCities = require('./function_new');

exports.lysearch = async (req, res) => {
try {
 //const listCities = function_new.listCities || []; //don't need to use this line
 return res.render('layouts/search_job', { listCities : listCities }); //send data using key-value pair.
} catch (error) {
  console.error('error:', error);
   return res.status(500).send('error 500');
  } 
};

Data fetching in your search_job.ejs seems to me correct.
Try all the above mentioned step and let me know if you have issue.

Thank you for your enthusiastic support. However, your solution doesn't really solve the problem I'm facing. It is not related to the listCities variable.

didn;t you get this renders an error: listCities is not defined at eval that mentioned in your question?What error you have found during running the above code?

@TúNgôNgọc What specific problem currently you are facing ?

To access variables in includes directly - without passing through a parent view, one way is to use global object as below.
server.js
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const app = express();

app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  global.listCities = [
    {
      cit_id: 1,
      cit_name: 'city-1',
    },
    {
      cit_id: 2,
      cit_name: 'city-2',
    },
    {
      cit_id: 3,
      cit_name: 'city-3',
    },
  ];
  res.render('main');
  delete global.listCities;
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});

included_template.ejs
<select id="s_loc">
  <% if (listCities && listCities.length > 0) { %> <%
  listCities.forEach(function(item) { %>
  <option value="<%= item.cit_id %>"><%= item.cit_name %></option>
  <% }); %> <% } %>
</select>

main.ejs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Main Template</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Main Template</h1>
    <%- include('included_template.ejs') %>
  </body>
</html>

Citation:
How to include a template with parameters in EJS ?
Is it safe to use and update global variables in NodeJS?
Output:

